# Convert MediaWiki Markup to Textile Markup

Tags: converters, markup, textile, redcloth, wikitext

I have a problem :0
At my place of work we have two wiki systems and I have been charged with finding a way of migrating from a MediaWiki to a redmine wiki -- only problem is they use different markup languages (WikiText vs Textile) and a possible solution (Pandoc) only goes the other way :0 Any suggestions on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MediaWiki to Redmine Migration Tool (MRMT)](https://github.com/GSI/mrmt) has just been released.

It migrates the whole history with the correct user assigned to each revision.

Besides a basic **Pandoc** translation it also adds some helpful replacements that will very likely be necessary in any migration of that kind.

Answer (score 1):

The development version of pandoc now has a mediawiki reader.  It doesn't support all of mediawiki syntax (e.g. templates), and it is not very well tested, but you could try it out.

You would need to install the development version of pandoc from source to do this. Install the Haskell Platform, then follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/wiki/Installing-the-development-version-of-pandoc-1.10).
(These instructions assume a *nix build environment.)

You will probably want to use some scripting to adjust the result, e.g. making links with title "wikilink" into proper redmine wikilinks.  It is easiest to do this at the level of the pandoc AST, rather than in the textile result. The document on [Scripting with pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/scripting.html) on the pandoc website may be of help here.

Another approach is to scrape the HTML your redmine wiki produces, and use pandoc to convert that to textile.  This approach typically requires a lot of preprocessing and postprocessing, though.

You could also try using one of the various [alternative mediawiki parsers](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Alternative_parsers), producing HTML or DocBook and converting that to textile using pandoc.

Comment: This is in stable now.